# Using Windows Media Player in C# for sound

Tags: c#, windows, audio, windows-media-player

So I've gone through about 10000 forums and postings that go about explaining how to use WindowsMediaPlayer for sound in my C# application.

What I have so far is

```
        WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer axMusicPlayer = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();

        string path = Path.GetFullPath("music.mp3");

        axMusicPlayer.URL = path;

        axMusicPlayer.settings.setMode("loop", true);

        axMusicPlayer.controls.play();
```

Now, according to a million people this should work, but when I run the application there is no sound, maybe I'm missing something, but I've just about reached my breaking point with this one. I know you can use SoundPlayer, but I'm reserving that for sound effects, which is why I want to use WindowsMediaPlayer for music.

Comment: If you use `WPF`, you should go for `MediaElement` which can play all kinds of sound Windows Media Player can.

Comment: is your sound card/head phone/ speaker working?

Comment: Yea, my sound is working fine, I'm 100% sure of this.

Comment: @user2728238 Where is the mp3 file located????

Comment: Thanks to Precious1tj I went into my program and checked something, and it turns out that Path.GetFullPath("music.mp3"); was pointing to ...\bin\debug\music.mp3, I assumed that Path.GetFullPath would find the music.mp3 file located in the Resource folder, now that I have moved the music.mp3 file to the debug folder, what happens is the music plays for about a second then abruptly stops. The headaches just don't stop...

Comment: Did you check with .wma  audio file? Windows media player syncs well with wma and wmv files.

Answer (score 0):

Try playing a `.wav` file. That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try using the .. command to go to the parent directory in your file path.

Since the default path for GetFullPath takes you into the MyProject\bin\Debug folders you need to get back to MyProject

For example:

```
    string path = Path.GetFullPath(@"..\..\music.mp3");
```

This will take you out of the Debug and bin folders and to the main folder of your project.

I tried to use your solution and this worked for me!